# «Носящий имя Героя Советского Союза, участника Великой Отечественной войны». Ставить ли запятую?

Tags: однородные-неоднородные-определения

«Носящий имя Героя Советского Союза, участника Великой Отечественной войны». Ставить ли запятую перед «участником»?

Comment: А полное предложение как выглядит?

Answer (score 1):

**Носящий имя Героя Советского Союза, участника Великой Отечественной войны.**

**Запятую ставим,** обозначая однородные отношения.

Сравнить: носящий имя человека, бывшего Героем Советского Союза и участником Великой Отечественной войны.

Правила для однородных и неоднородных приложений здесь не действуют, так как нет определяемого существительного.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть имя (определяемое существительное), то я бы писал:

**Это корабль, носящий имя участника Великой Отечественной войны Героя Советского Союза Иванова.**

Если написать **Это корабль, носящий имя Героя Советского Союза, участника Великой Отечественной войны Иванова**, то связи звания и участия в войне нет, можно подумать, что он звание получил до или после войны.

А если имя героя не упоминается, то см. ответ Sharon.